# Generate page url jquery

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing, url-parameters

I want redirect from index page to other page passing id.
in html i have this code   
I'm using jquery and i have this code.

```
$("<a class='theme-btn default-btn' href='#'>Read more </a></button>").appendTo($target).click(function() {
                    document.location.href='post.html?id=' + $id;
                });
```

After redirecting the url is > http://example.com/post?id=14
I want to be like this>  **http://example.com/post/this-is-the-post-title**
How i can do this?

Comment: Can you a sample work on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: in html i have <div id = "target"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do.
You'll have to do that server-side, with a rewrite URL.

Depending on your server-setup, this will either be inside your web.config (for IIS) or in htaccess (Apache).

Here's an example of what an IIS Rewrite rule looks like, in the context of your question.

```
<rule name="Category Rule">
    <match url="post/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)*.aspx" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="post.aspx?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

If the URL was; /post.aspx?id=14
This would return the URL /post/14

In order for this to work, your page would need some sort of logic to determine which content was shown, depending on the ID of the page. For instance, which row of a database to grab the content of the page for.